# Can I implement MVVM with Binding in Xamarin.Android?

Tags: c#, android, mvvm, xamarin

I'm trying to implement an Android client for my current Universal App application using Shared Project with running clients in Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 (Store).

Every developer here is used to MVVM and it's applied to our current clients but it seems not to be possible to do with Xamarin.Android. Does anyone know if there's an API or any workaround for it?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

There are several MVVM frameworks that are compatible with Xamarin

[MVVM Cross](https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross) and [MVVM Light](https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/) are the two most well known, but there are others.